# Using MySQL to work out the historical rank of a value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a table of historical rank data. My output should look something like the following:

| date | value | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1500 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1200 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 1700 | 5 |
| 2022-01-02 | 1100 | 2 |
| 2022-01-03 | 1600 | 6 |
| 2022-01-03 | 1400 | 4 |

So for 2022-01-01 I'm only ranking the values set on that day.

For 2022-01-02, I'm ranking the values set on that day *and* the day before

For 2022-01-03, I'm ranking the values set on that day and **all** the days before, etc...

The table I'll actually be running this on spans many years and thousands of entries per date. I've been experimenting with window functions to no avail as I am not sure if it's even possible to run a window function with overlapping partitions, because below is what I thought would work.

```sql
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY <= `date` ORDER BY value ASC) AS `rank` FROM tableName;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to have overlapping partitions, but I don't know how to do it myself. Show what you tried.

Comment: I was trying something like `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY <= \`date\` ORDER BY value ASC) AS \`rank\` FROM tableName;` but syntax error

Comment: Add what you tried to the question.

Comment: Done. I realised my expected rank values were wrong so fixed them too.

Comment: Use 2 table copies.

Comment: @Akina I wanted to avoid that because the actual table I'm working on has about 30 million rows. Unless you have a more efficient way of using table copies that I'm not seeing?

Comment: *ause the actual table I'm working on has about 30 million rows* Do you want to "rank" all 30kk rows?

Comment: I want every row to have a rank, yes. They won't necessarily be ranked against all other entries, as I have various groups that need to be ranked, but not against each other, if that makes sense. Like I'm making ranks within a country, but not a world rank.

Comment: So in my actual database, I would have something like `PARTITION BY <=date, countryId...` etc. if that would work. But that would be on every single row.